# Convert JSON format in specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have JSON object like

`countryMap = Object {KE: 10, BR: 9, NP: 7}`

Now I want it in form like

```
[
      {
          "code": "KE",
          "value": 10
      },
      {
          "code": "BR",
          "value": 9
      },
      {
          "code": "NP",
          "value": 7
      }

];
```

What I tried is

```
$.each(countryMap, function(key, value){
        item = {};
        item ["code"] = key;
        item ["value"] = value;
        totalCountries+=1;
        jsonObj.push(item);
});
```

But what I am getting is

```
    [
      {
          "code": "KE"
          "value": 10
      },
      {
          "code": "BR"
          "value": 9
      },
      {
          "code": "NP"
          "value": 7
      }

];
```

Note that missing `comma` after code value.

How do I achieve exact format which I want?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: There's no way your object is missing the commas, you're just reading it wrong ?

Comment: how you print your array?

Comment: You could also do `Object.keys(countryMap).map( k => ({code : k, value : countryMap[k]}));`

Comment: Please create a snippet to demonstrate the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this..

```js
countryMap = {KE: 10, BR: 9, NP: 7};
var jsonObj=[];
$.each(countryMap, function(key, val){
        jsonObj.push({code:key,value:val});
}); 
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's the exact same code (only minified). Why should this be an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$.each(countryMap, function(key, value){
   item = {"code": key, "value": value};
   totalCountries+=1;
   jsonObj.push(item);
});
```